# In a ring $R$, Show that if $x^2 =0$ then $x-1$ and $x+1$ are units .

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, $x$ in $R$, show that if $x^2 =0$ then $x-1$ and $x+1$ are units.

I tried by squaring $x+1$ and $x-1$ but this did not help.
How i can start?

Comment: You should try to expand $(1-x)(1+x)$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$ x^2=0 \implies x^2-1=-1$$
$$ (x+1)(x-1)=x^2-1=-1$$
$$ -(x+1)(x-1)=1$$
From this, we can clearly see what the inverse of each element is.

Comment: Is this enough to prove x- and 1 x+1 are units

Comment: Certainly! This last equation tells us that $-(x+1)$ is the inverse of $(x-1)$ and $-(x-1)$ is the inverse of $(x+1)$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
(x-1)(x+1) = x^2 - 1 = -1.
$$
This puts us one step away from simultaneously proving that both $x-1$ and $x+1$ are units.